# Reentering UK with a Standard Visitor Visa

Tags: visas, standard-visitor-visas

I am applying for a Standard Visitor Visa as I am going to an academic conference in the UK.

My question is that I am considering going back for leisure purposes, but no definite plans yet.

Both reasons are covered by a Standard Visitor Visa. As the second entry is not set in stone yet, I don't have any documents for that.

Assuming that my visa for the conference has not still expired by then, can I return for leisure purposes sometime after (when and if I decide to)? Or would I have to reapply for a new one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The UK standard visitor visa covers both Lesuire and non-paid professional activities like conferences and meetings. You should meet the main purpose of your Visa and this to attend the academic conference.
You don't need to explain your future leisure plan with ECO yet, however whenever you plan to visit the UK for leisure purposes in future make sure you carry following documents to satisfy the immigration officer.

- Leave letter from office/Employer
- Leave letter from College/University (if Student)
- Proof of funds like (Credit Card etc)
- Hotel Booking
- Should be able to explain your leisure activities (like places you will be visiting or relatives you will be meeting.

I hope this clarifies your query!

Thanks!